# BLFS Xorg: Fatal server error no screens found

Tags: xorg, virtualbox, x-server, lfs

I'm trying to build the Xorg X Window System Environment as outlined in Beyond Linux From Scratch Version 8.0. My BLFS system resides in a Virtual Machine using VirtualBox Version 5.0.10 r104061.

I followed the steps as outlined in Chapter 24. X Window System Environment. However, when I finished my installation and tried startx, I got the output below:-

```
Release Date: 2017-01-11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.5 x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux LFS 4.9.5 #1 SMP Thu Feb 23 22:59:41 GMT 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.5-lfs-SVN-20170122 root=/dev/sda1 ro
Build Date: 01 March 2017  10:04:52PM

Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 22 21:42:24 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

And I see the following log in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
   57.972]
X.Org X Server 1.19.1
Release Date: 2017-01-11
[    57.974] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    57.974] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.5 x86_64
[    57.975] Current Operating System: Linux LFS 4.9.5 #1 SMP Thu Feb 23 22:59:41 GMT 2017 x86_64
[    57.975] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.5-lfs-SVN-20170122 root=/dev/sda1 ro
[    57.975] Build Date: 01 March 2017  10:04:52PM
[    57.975]
[    57.975] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    57.975]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    57.975] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    57.978] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 22 21:42:24 2017
[    57.990] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    57.992] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    57.992] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    57.992] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    57.992] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    57.992] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using the first device section listed.
[    57.992] (**) |   |-->Device "radeon"
[    57.992] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
        Using a default monitor configuration.
[    57.992] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    57.992] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    57.992] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    57.994] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    57.999] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/".
[    57.999]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    57.999]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/").
[    58.002] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/".
[    58.002]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    58.002]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/").
[    58.003] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/".
[    58.003]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    58.003]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/").
[    58.003] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/TTF/,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/OTF/,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/
[    58.003] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    58.003] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    58.003] (II) Loader magic: 0x810c40
[    58.003] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    58.003]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    58.003]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[    58.003]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    58.003]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    58.007] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 80ee:beef:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    58.007] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[    58.007] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    58.008] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    58.040] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    58.040]    compiled for 1.19.1, module version = 1.0.0
[    58.040]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    58.040] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    58.041] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    58.042] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    58.042]    compiled for 1.19.1, module version = 7.8.0
[    58.042]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    58.042]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[    58.042] (EE) No drivers available.
[    58.042] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    58.044] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    58.045] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    58.046] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    58.046] (EE)
[    58.046] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I've tried rebuilding the kernel with

```
Device Drivers  --->
  Graphics support  --->
   <*> Direct Rendering Manager (XFree86 ... support) --->  [CONFIG_DRM]
   <*> DRM driver for VMware Virtual GPU                    [CONFIG_DRM_VMWGFX]
      [*]   Enable framebuffer console under vmwgfx by default [CONFIG_DRM_VMWGFX_FBCON]
```

and

```
Device Drivers  --->
  Graphics support  --->
   <> Direct Rendering Manager (XFree86 ... support) --->  [CONFIG_DRM]
```

and in both cases got the same error message. This is the output of lspci for the graphics adapter

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
```

Any idea why the screens are failing to load?

Comment: in log file there is information about graphic modules/drivers it tries out - glx and ati (both expect some 3D support). then there is first error `(EE) No drivers available.`. and `lspci` shows you have `VGA compatible controler`. maybe you can change graphic card settings in your virtual machine? this should help, because Xorg so far looks fine.

Comment: oh and lfs has very helpful community, you can ask this question on blfs-support mailing list http://lists.linuxfromscratch.org/listinfo/blfs-support/

Answer (score 0):

The answer I posted here might help: [Setting up vnc server and no physical display : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326234/setting-up-vnc-server-and-no-physical-display-ubuntu-16-04-lts/326238#326238)

It sets up a virtual screen for the X stack to send output to, letting it finish starting up the GUI environment.